# Why isn't my $scope dependency resolved when I add it to the Angular Seed View1Ctrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-seed

I am experimenting with **Angular Seed** and I tried to add a `$scope` dependency to the `View1Ctrl` as follows:

```
 .controller('View1Ctrl', [function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'mundo';
    }]);
```

which does not work: `$scope` is `undefined`...

When I change the code to this:

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'mundo';
    });
```

then `$scope` is resolved.

Can someone please explain why `$scope` is not resolved with the first snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use the [] you need to provide strings to match the dependency's to inject.

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'mundo';
}]);
```

This is useful if you minify your javascript,

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function (a) {
    a.message = 'mundo';
}]);
```

This means the $scope is injected as a variable named a. Without the [] it attempts to inject whatever the variable name is.